# Apple HomeKit HMCharacteristics

Tags: ios, swift, homekit, home-automation, hmcharacteristic

I'm currently working on a quite important study project.
I'm working on the topic of home automation. Therefore I would like to implement the HomeKit framework to control action modules.

My App is already able to search for Homes, Rooms, Accessories, Services and Characteristics. But I don't know how to properly handle all of the different characteristic types. Is there a way to get the characteristic type as real string (for example: `HMCharacteristicTypePowerState`).

I really don't know how to present the user just those characteristics that matter.

I would appreciate if someone could drop me a hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

`HMCharacteristic` has a `characteristicType` property, which you can compare to the constants.

```
if characteristic.characteristicType == HMCharacteristicTypePowerState {
    // do something
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HMCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Characteristic_Types)

Comment: Yeah I worked it out that way to. But for some reason there are still Characteristics that aren't defined by apple, that I can't access that way. For example the current power draw of an power outlet.

Comment: So you're saying the characteristic has a type not defined by any of those constants? Is it an unofficial HomeKit accessory? What is the value of `characteristicType` for those characteristics?

Comment: Just in case anyone is doing this with ObjectiveC, you'll need to use isEqualToString, not ==.

Answer (score 0):

`HMCharacteristic` has a `localizedDescription` property which returns a readable string, but if you want to select only certain characteristics it is better to use the the `HMCharacteristicsType` constants as suggested by Mark

Answer (score -1):

```
if characteristic.characteristicType isEqualToString: HMCharacteristicTypePowerState {
    // do something
}
```